# Constructing images and loading

Tags: python, pygame

I have a super class Sprite and a sub class character:

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__self(self,Image,position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image =pygame.image.load(Image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos

class Character(Sprite):
     character = pygame.sprite.Group()
     def __init__(self):
         self.finalimage = pygame.Surface([5, 5])
         self.image = self.finalimage
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

In the Character class I have methods setimage and collision.I use the sprite class to check if a character collides with another for example:

```
    sprite = Sprite(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
    self.character.add(sprite)                 
    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, Background.character, True)
```

So i need to call the sprite class for collisions. My problem is when I try and give a image to the sprite in the sprite class this is the image which stays when I Use this class, when I give the image object from the constructor I get the error :

> pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source

**from this line:  self.image =pygame.image.load(Image)**

Is there a neat way of overriding/ providing your own images? Clearly my logic doesnt work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show full traceback. Is `self.image` a filename in `sprite = Sprite(self.image,(self.x,self.y))` ?

Answer (score 1):

`self.image` has to be a filename (or file object) in `sprite = Sprite(self.image,(self.x,self.y))` but it seems you have surface in `self.image`

```
# class Character
self.finalimage = pygame.Surface([5, 5]) # finalimage is Surface
self.image = self.finalimage # finalimage is Surface so image is Surface
# ...
sprite = Sprite(self.image,(self.x,self.y)) # image is Surface

# class Sprite
def __init__self(self,Image,position): # so Image is Surface
    # ...
    self.image =pygame.image.load(Image) # so Image is Surface
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo, i retyped this out :L